# Create a project's Geoserver repository

Tags: git, tomcat6, geoserver

I've been working with a previous installation of Geoserver (1.7), I have managed to update it to Geoserver 2.5 (the latest version that won't require me to update the old server's tomcat6 to tomcat7+).

We are moving slowly to the latest version and I'm going to create a git repository to keep track of the Geoserver installation using git. But I'm not sure what to add to my `.gitignore` I don't want any passwords and users to leak into the public github repository while keeping the most complete geoserver installation so it can easily be `git clone`ed and installed.

Currently my `.gitignore` file looks like this:

```
catalog.xml
catalog.xml.*
!catalog.xml.sample
logs/*
```

Are there any files or directories that I should remove.

I couldn't find any question on this topic, or any tutorial on best practices to create/maintain a geoserver repository (I was planning to add to the repository the whole tomcat6 webapp geoserver not just the `data` directory) so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

*Update*
In the meantime my .gitignore is looking like this: (Wondering if I should just .gitignore the whole security directory)

```
catalog.xml
catalog.xml.*
!catalog.xml.sample
logs/*
data/security/users.properties.*
!data/security/users.properties.sample
data/security/masterpw/*
data/security/masterpw.*
data/security/usergroup/default/users.xml
data/security/geoserver.jceks
```

Comment: I dont know Geoserver but here is a list of ".gitignore templates" for a lot of different projects. Hope it helps https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful link I'll bookmark it for future reference but alas it doesn't contain geoserver